# Is it possible to run first sampler for all the users and then procced to second sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, sequential

I need to run first one sampler for all the users and proceed to second sampler. I have thread group with two samplers Login and Form submit as below

Thread Group

- Login sampler
- Form Submit sampler

I am running for 100 users with ramp-up time of 50 secs, first JMeter needs to complete Login sampler first and then proceed with Form submit sampler by 100 users in 50 secs.

At a same time only one action needs to be performed by the JMeter

Answer (score 0):

All JMeter threads (virtual users) execute [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) upside down so you don't need to do anything, each virtual user will first execute the login sampler then submit the form.

If you want all 100 users to login first and only then start submitting the forms - add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) as a child of the Login Sampler and set the number of simulated users to group by to be equal to the number of threads in the Thread Group

If you want JMeter to perform only one action at the given moment, i.e. you don't need any concurrency - put your samplers under the [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, 
Thanks for your reply, but I need to wait till login requests are successfully completed (response also) and then start the form submission, while using Synchronizing Timer all the login requests are first sent and then form submission requests are triggered. Where as I need to wait till all login requests getting completed.

Comment: Add another Synchronizing Timer as a child of the 2nd request or move it to the same level so it would be applied to both Samplers. See [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more details